# Generic Schema for Custom component with drag & drop support

Tags: etl, talend, sap-r3

I'm making new talend components which is working fine. These will be under Databases/SAP (Its an SAP R/3 table input).

I'm stuck with using Drag & Drop for the schema then select an appropriate component from the pop up list just like we have with other Db connections.

How should I set up my component XML to have this working?

Here's my current XML: http://sharetext.org/eXUL

I've attached some screenshot how it looks like right now.
[image: Schema details]
[image: After import]
[image: Drag & Drop not supported]

Comment: i would compare the xml you have against xml of any existing component like tMssqlOutput to see what is the difference for PARAMETER NAME="SCHEMA_FLOW" & PARAMETER NAME="SCHEMA_REJECT".. may be you can post your xml

Comment: I've uploaded the xml to: http://sharetext.org/eXUL

Answer (score 0):

According to Talend:

```
Hi
I have consulted our developer and confirmed that drag & drop is not supported from 
generic schema now. This is related to UI development, not component creation, 
I suggest you to report a feature issue on our bugtracker.

Shong
```

I've created a JIRA request: https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI-29100